# Combining two collections, retaining the sort order then displaying in staggered format

Tags: c#, list, sorting, collections

I need to combine two different collections and display them together in staggered format.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var NewsList = new List<DateTime>();
        NewsList.Add(new DateTime(2016, 9, 25));
        NewsList.Add(new DateTime(2016, 10, 15));
        NewsList.Add(new DateTime(2016, 10, 24));
        NewsList.Add(new DateTime(2016, 10, 27));
        NewsList.Add(new DateTime(2016, 10, 31));

        var EventList = new List<DateTime>();
        EventList.Add(new DateTime(2016, 10, 31));
        EventList.Add(new DateTime(2016, 11, 1));
        EventList.Add(new DateTime(2016, 11, 4));
        EventList.Add(new DateTime(2016, 11, 5));
        EventList.Add(new DateTime(2016, 11, 10));

        var CombinedList = EventList.Union(NewsList).OrderBy(i => i);

        Display(SortDescending(NewsList), "News List SortDescending - Newsest To Oldest"); 
        Display(SortAscending(EventList), "Event List SortAscending - Oldest To Newest");
        DisplayCombined(CombinedList, "ComindedList");

    }

    /// Displays the list from Oldest -> Newest 
    static List<DateTime> SortAscending(List<DateTime> list)
    {
        list.Sort((a, b) => a.CompareTo(b));
        return list;
    }

    /// Displays the list from Newest -> Oldest  
    static List<DateTime> SortDescending(List<DateTime> list)
    {
        list.Sort((a, b) => b.CompareTo(a));
        return list;
    }

    static void Display(List<DateTime> list,  string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        foreach (var datetime in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(datetime);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }  

    static void DisplayCombined(IEnumerable<DateTime> list, string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        foreach (var datetime in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(datetime);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadLine();
    } 
}
```

As you will see above, I've attempted to use a union which combines the two lists, this displays the entire combined collection in ascending order as set by the OrderBy method (in this case OrderBy(i => i)). If no order is set explicitly, then by default it will return each item held, first from the EventsList then from the NewsList, whilst maintaining the order originally set for both lists.

What I'd like to display would be a staggered list, so I am getting one item from one list then one item from the next etc etc.... as such

- 2016, 10, 31 First Event Item
- 2016, 9, 25 First News Item
- 2016, 11, 1 Second Event Item
- 2016, 10, 15 Second News Item
- 2016, 11, 4 Third Event Item
- 2016, 10, 24 Third News Item

Comment: `Concat` in LINQ?

Comment: Well you told it to order by them, so you are changing the order..

Comment: Is it "each item from list 1 should be followed by the corresponding item from list 2, based on list indexes?". If not, how do we know when to insert an item from list 2 into list 1s values, when the values aren't sorted by date?

Comment: What do you mean by "combine"? In what way should they be combined? What is the result that you expect?

Comment: @BugFinder - If I remove the Order by from the CombinedList, then it gets the list of items from events, then from news.

Comment: I've amend my original question to answer what it is I'd like to display

Comment: Oh so you want them spliced together??

Comment: @BugFinder, not sure as am not familiar with spliced, is this somthing else that would work?

Comment: @BugFinder, I've just read about splice here @ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72x0hey1(v=vs.100).aspx, but from the description doesn't seem like it would do what I needed?

Comment: No splice is the description of what you want doing, the way a pro shuffler of cards splices the two halves together so the interlace..

Comment: ok thanks, I'll take a closer look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your `CombinedList` contain classes that contain two values, the event date and the news date. For example:

```
var combinedList = NewsList.Zip(EventList, 
    (first, second) => { return new {EventDate = first, NewsDate = second}; });
int i = 1;
foreach (var x in combinedList)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Event {i}: {x.EventDate}");
    Console.WriteLine($"News {i}: {x.NewsDate}");
    ++i;
}
```

This assumes that the `EventList` and `NewsList` have the same number of items. If one is longer than the other, then those additional items will be lost.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.